# Bootstrap классы внутри PHP блока

Tags: php, html, mysql, база-данных, bootstrap

Цель такая, нужно вывыести данные из БД в виде таблицы. Всё работает,но не красиво, хотел подключить bootstrap и сделать покрасивее. Вне блока PHP он работает, но когда придаю классы тегам html внутри блока php то он распознает это как синтаксическую ошибку. Как это обойти? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в кавычках. Замените двойные кавычки в фрагменте `class='table'` на одинарные.

Либо экранируйте двойные кавычки: `class=\"table\"`

Comment: Да, спасибо. Ранее уже сам догодался, но мой ответ удалили :/